# Redirecting Devise After Sign Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What's the best practice for redirecting the user, using Devise, back to the page she is currently on after she logs out?

The [devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out) say to override the following (in your application controller):

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  # logic here
end
```

Which is easy enough. However, I'm setting the previous page to be a session variable, like this:

```
session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
```

The problem is that when you sign out, the session is destroyed, and the top method occurs AFTER the session is destroyed, meaning you no longer have access to it. I'm thinking of putting it in a class variable or something similar, but wanted to see what SO thought.

Comment: Maybe try setting the return_to path in the flash instead of the session e.g. flash[:return_to]

Comment: interesting thought - i'd be happy to create a class variable, but it's not clear what the method execution ordering is, and the docs don't help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are always using the page where the logout link was clicked you could use the referrer on the request.

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  request.referrer
end
```

Comment: Interesting, i had totally ignored that because i had to do all kinds of work on the front side to make sure they weren't on the sign-in page, but i think that works!

Comment: So great. Exactly what I'd been trying to do for ages. Thanks for an awesome answer!

Comment: Be aware, though, that not all browsers send the referrer within the request. Add blockers may hide it, too. You should always have a save backup target, let it only be '/'.

Comment: if you are wondering where to put it, here is a good example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824479/devise-method-after-sign-in-path-for-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect user to sign in page after sign out write the below function in you application controller

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end
```