# devise method after_sign_in_path_for doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to control redirecting after user is logged in. I found many answers to this problem point to after_sign_in_path_for method. So i added this to my application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    raise "SIGN IN TEST"
    dashboard_path
end
```

to check out how this works. But whenever i log in, there are no exceptions raised, method is just ignored. What shall I do to make devise use it?

EDIT
as requested, fragment of routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    :sessions => "user/sessions",
    :registrations => "user/registrations",
    :passwords => 'user/passwords'
  }
```

Comment: does this method run after sign in? raise "SIGN IN PATH" needs an end " mark

Comment: no it doesnt run after sign in, thats the whole point of my question

Comment: where have you overriden this method?

Comment: in application_controller.rb

Comment: if it is under `private` move it to `protected`

Comment: Can you please write the sessions/create method , need to check the method is calling from here or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official docs for this are here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out)

--

We use this successfully like this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        dashboard_path
    end
end
```

--

If your method is not being called, you'll want to firstly remove the `RAISE` call and try again by restarting your server. If this does not work, the issue will likely be with how `Devise` is working on your system

If you could try removing `RAISE` & letting us know the result, it will be a great help!

---

**Update**

EVEN BETTER that you're using `users/sessions` controller. Here's ours:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    ####################
    #    Redirects     #
    ####################

    protected

    #Login Path (if already logged in)
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        dashboard_path
    end

    #Logout Path
    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        root_url
    end

end
```

Comment: i removed raise, restarted server and simply logged in, nothing new has been noticed

Comment: Thanks buddy. Can you show us your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: i cant really give the whole file because im not the owner, but in a second i will update me question with piece reflecting on signing in

Comment: `im not the owner` could be the problem right there -- there's definitely something going on behind the scenes!

Comment: thx to your edit i noticed that somebody has already overriden this method, it probably why it didnt work