# Changing route after sign out with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rubygems

I am creating a website using rails and I have started using the devise gem. I have added a sign out link to my homepage which works, but I want to route the user back to the login page after they sign out. At this moment after the user signs in they are offered a sign out link which signs them out but they remain at the page. How do I make it so that they are sent back to the login page after they sign out? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514421/redirecting-devise-after-sign-out?rq=1 including reading the Devise documentation mentioned in that page?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the redirect path in `ApplicationController` using Devise's `after_sign_out_path_for` method...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I added this and now I get an error when i click sign out it says i need to be signed in in order to sign out, but when i try to sign in it says I'm ready signed in. What should i do now?